# How to reduce selects postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-range

For example I have 5 data with info:

```
tool_id | start_date |  end_date  | project_id
--------------------------------------------
   4    | 2018-02-05 | 2018-12-08 |    5
   4    | 2018-05-23 | 2018-07-07 |    6
   4    | 2018-03-07 | 2019-02-26 |    7
   4    | 2020-01-01 | 2020-08-01 |    8
   4    | 2018-01-05 | 2018-04-06 |    9
```

I want to calculate a date intervals, but if dates of next project are between previous projects' dates, it wouldn't include to interval... I wrote the function with Typescript [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFIgDYQFwwN5wYgkgEzTAFcBbAIwFMAnAGhmgEMqoARBqCtaKgSzAHMYAHxhsOdCmDxjO9KLwHDR7CnQAOVEACsKwKPkKlKVGAF8A2gF0YAXhjmAUDGcYnL9-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-pgBQnrKBw-otlQbY4GAp4vqu36WDG6itu2qH+uhMjmDEWEwAkMAxDhSF4Wh-5EREWF0FETEsTAUQxleNZ1naDpOsADCIMALA8Na1oALLgFAAAWAb7jEU4RkWEQKRwk4wMQ5DUPGLi3rAeAidan67jAYnsFJB4MGQskqBEB4AG4CUQFBdta-pxuRcn2Y5zmuRx14uGBEEmWZB6aHaeCBgZRmAjA-oxFECUwAAVGqoIpX2yUwBEPh+VxDiIB68q2Gx1YFXpKgAEoMAIFAKnYVgwAwCqYGGsghuWNThumFiWCB1ogCY-plTAWjFVElYjaWzzIAeBUCNJE1aAA1EtcYztNEDmFov6tcViHId2vYDkOKj+uMm3bUeswhCojUKmOAicR42AXb+Wp7bhnY9n2MSDsO51bW9Fbpk1cgKBOIE3uAd7AMmiaocVAPbf5zgibF+5VTVECzZI-DSWtDLDWoRAQFJxXWgJbYo4Ew3gBQ0V2PITnU+4-WDcNPBjRNnNlhj1X8LVOPzVJ3MrQTTxQ-OMCw1Q8NQJjAvFXzWPmDwvUMu4aP+jLctXTmt1ljrkjy-zh67QWzpuh63q+ioAZG6hB7vaD7UOybNV6zd4jS3DxsK4eWocdpEuBCU5QwEtdj8YJwmiRJqEydrvuof7nurnQbtp7mLsqE9Ieh5VpubWrWe3VHydQKXIMKjILP53TDMwBTyAUHX2ymIyLfOtasWZ+9WZu6n70Wy67pej6YB+knsvG1XxY597g+m3PGcV0PwMUEH6350VkfSwJQkGfH0n2xXTsb3dcGqD7M8p8vgdtxLysC8XQOdcZfcXwvrca+cDfbsZZuVNf7OA7hQLuWtM67UNmvZe5tCyf3fpmG+ct17v3FjvFwYcFR72jofOOklE5Lw9q1Vet9K67W-nGJa+8Y5H0Iafch58kHfzIag++G886YKLP7V+c9ipQOuquS+tcQEFw4Lw1Wb8nwoNns7GuVYxHuH-jucmlMf47zARAnu-pR7WwnlPQR+tq5XzYX7OBQjXawI9oHfMhY9Hj1thwRhut5GmNkXfEhljFLEIFsw2MGDuFAjwCAdSIBpLjiUS4FRgD1GP3cFotswdMHE1JojKgzMxG1ieNk84WtUlkwtjEwJT9wQRyjgfWO4kGHT11pQhRi8z5uNjGI5+gsCn+hat45kRivbzwadfLUaBEHZwGWYLhgRcmgM7kk7eWCym4MqfQhOLjZ71PcSM26VDH5tOxh0rpxjZC9OEawjqexNkmNzKYCZtY8q3iQIeRAIB+BnhIAwgE2CYwOHuQVWazyzy7I+YXLGMYgA)...

Theoretically of above code looks like:

1. `dateRange = [], days = 0` (because first project for current tool) `start_date = 2018-02-05, end_date = 2018-12-08`, so we are pushing dates to dateRange and calculate days -> `dateRange = [{ start_date: 2018-02-05, end_date: 2018-12-08 }], days = 306`
2. Next: `start_date = 2018-05-23, end_date = 2018-07-07`, start_date and end_date are between date ranges. So temp variables are left as it is `dateRange = [{ start_date: 2018-02-05, end_date: 2018-12-08 }], days = 306`
3. Next: `start_date = 2018-03-07, end_date = 2019-02-26`, start_date is between date ranges, but end_date is bigger than dateRange's end_date. So we are changing `dateRange[0].end_date` to current end_date and add to days interval between `end_date - dateRange[0].end_date`.. Finally `dateRange = [{ start_date: 2018-02-05, end_date: 2019-02-26 }], days = 386`
4. Next: `start_date = 2020-01-01, end_date = 2020-08-01`, start_date and end_date are not between in dateRanges element, so we need to push to dateRange and add to days the interval of start_date and end_date.. Finally `dateRange = [{ start_date: 2018-02-05, end_date: 2019-02-26 }, {start_date: 2020-01-01, end_date: 2020-08-01}], days = 599`
5. Next: `start_date = 2018-01-05, end_date = 2019-04-06`, end_date is between first element of date ranges, but start_date is less than first element of dateRange's start_date. So we are changing `dateRange[0].start_date` to current start_date and add to days interval between `dateRange[0].start_date - start_date`.. Finally `dateRange = [{ start_date: 2018-01-05, end_date: 2019-02-26 }, {start_date: 2020-01-01, end_date: 2020-08-01}], days = 630`

**That's it.. I want to rewrite [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFIgDYQFwwN5wYgkgEzTAFcBbAIwFMAnAGhmgEMqoARBqCtaKgSzAHMYAHxhsOdCmDxjO9KLwHDR7CnQAOVEACsKwKPkKlKVGAF8A2gF0YAXhjmAUDGcYnL9-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-pgBQnrKBw-otlQbY4GAp4vqu36WDG6itu2qH+uhMjmDEWEwAkMAxDhSF4Wh-5EREWF0FETEsTAUQxleNZ1naDpOsADCIMALA8Na1oALLgFAAAWAb7jEU4RkWEQKRwk4wMQ5DUPGLi3rAeAidan67jAYnsFJB4MGQskqBEB4AG4CUQFBdta-pxuRcn2Y5zmuRx14uGBEEmWZB6aHaeCBgZRmAjA-oxFECUwAAVGqoIpX2yUwBEPh+VxDiIB68q2Gx1YFXpKgAEoMAIFAKnYVgwAwCqYGGsghuWNThumFiWCB1ogCY-plTAWjFVElYjaWzzIAeBUCNJE1aAA1EtcYztNEDmFov6tcViHId2vYDkOKj+uMm3bUeswhCojUKmOAicR42AXb+Wp7bhnY9n2MSDsO51bW9Fbpk1cgKBOIE3uAd7AMmiaocVAPbf5zgibF+5VTVECzZI-DSWtDLDWoRAQFJxXWgJbYo4Ew3gBQ0V2PITnU+4-WDcNPBjRNnNlhj1X8LVOPzVJ3MrQTTxQ-OMCw1Q8NQJjAvFXzWPmDwvUMu4aP+jLctXTmt1ljrkjy-zh67QWzpuh63q+ioAZG6hB7vaD7UOybNV6zd4jS3DxsK4eWocdpEuBCU5QwEtdj8YJwmiRJqEydrvuof7nurnQbtp7mLsqE9Ieh5VpubWrWe3VHydQKXIMKjILP53TDMwBTyAUHX2ymIyLfOtasWZ+9WZu6n70Wy67pej6YB+knsvG1XxY597g+m3PGcV0PwMUEH6350VkfSwJQkGfH0n2xXTsb3dcGqD7M8p8vgdtxLysC8XQOdcZfcXwvrca+cDfbsZZuVNf7OA7hQLuWtM67UNmvZe5tCyf3fpmG+ct17v3FjvFwYcFR72jofOOklE5Lw9q1Vet9K67W-nGJa+8Y5H0Iafch58kHfzIag++G886YKLP7V+c9ipQOuquS+tcQEFw4Lw1Wb8nwoNns7GuVYxHuH-jucmlMf47zARAnu-pR7WwnlPQR+tq5XzYX7OBQjXawI9oHfMhY9Hj1thwRhut5GmNkXfEhljFLEIFsw2MGDuFAjwCAdSIBpLjiUS4FRgD1GP3cFotswdMHE1JojKgzMxG1ieNk84WtUlkwtjEwJT9wQRyjgfWO4kGHT11pQhRi8z5uNjGI5+gsCn+hat45kRivbzwadfLUaBEHZwGWYLhgRcmgM7kk7eWCym4MqfQhOLjZ71PcSM26VDH5tOxh0rpxjZC9OEawjqexNkmNzKYCZtY8q3iQIeRAIB+BnhIAwgE2CYwOHuQVWazyzy7I+YXLGMYgA) to postgresql query**

I wrote query, but it works with just one dateRange:

```
SELECT 
    "projectTool"."toolId" AS "toolId",
    max(coalesce(project.end_date, current_date) - project.start_date) AS days
FROM "project_tools_tool" "projectTool"
LEFT JOIN "tool" "tool" ON "projectTool"."toolId" = "tool"."id"
LEFT JOIN "project" "project" ON "projectTool"."projectId" = "project"."id"
GROUP BY "projectTool"."toolId", "tool"."order"
ORDER BY "tool"."order" ASC
```

result is:

```
toolId: 4, days: 356 (it took just max start_date and end_date)
```

Expected result is

```
toolId: 4, days: 630
```

Comment: What is the expected "SQL" result?

Comment: @SalmanA I added to above description

Comment: As per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Looks like a merge overlapping intervals problem to me.

Comment: @SalmanA Do you think using recalculating in typescript as I wrote is better than writing in postgresql query? So I will get just projects of tool and calculate days in typescript

Comment: Could you please explain 4th step? How did you find 599?